# get current Material UI breakpoint name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, frontend

I'm searching a MUI function " `MaterialUIGiveMeCurrentBreakPointName`" that allows me to performe an action in a component like this:

```
const currentBreakPointName = MaterialUIGiveMeCurrentBreakPointName()

if(currentBreakPointName === 'myCustomBreakPointName') {
  // do stuff 
}
```

Could you help me out please ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Currently there is no such function available which will return you the current breakpoint name but you can achieve this using `useMediaQuery` hook.
**Refer** : https://mui.com/material-ui/react-use-media-query/ 
**Working codesandbox** : https://codesandbox.io/s/themehelper-demo-material-ui-forked-h2grmr?file=/demo.tsx

```
const theme = useTheme();
const greaterThanMid = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.up("md"));
const smallToMid = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.between("sm", "md"));
const lessThanSmall = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down("sm"));
if (greaterThanMid) {
  console.log("Greater than mid");
} else if (smallToMid) {
  console.log("Between small to mid");
} else if (lessThanSmall) {
  console.log("Less than small");
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For em @Apoplectic's answer was not working so I adapted it. It is still a custom hook.

```js
import {Theme, useTheme } from '@mui/material/styles' // or @mui/joy/styles
import useMediaQuery from "@mui/material/useMediaQuery";
import {Breakpoint} from "@mui/system";

/**
 * taken from https://material-ui.com/components/use-media-query/#migrating-from-withwidth
 *
 * Be careful using this hook. It only works because the number of
 * breakpoints in theme is static. It will break once you change the number of
 * breakpoints. See https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level
 */
type BreakpointOrNull = Breakpoint | null

export const useWidth = (): Breakpoint => {
    const theme: Theme = useTheme()
    const keys: readonly Breakpoint[] = [...theme.breakpoints.keys]
    console.log(keys);
    return (
        keys.reduce((output: BreakpointOrNull, key: Breakpoint) => {
            // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
            const matches = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.up(key))
            return matches ? key : output
        }, null) ?? 'xs'
    )
}
```

Usage

```js
const breakpoint = useWidth()
```

Comment: This is problematic, better us something without calling hooks conditionally

Answer (score 1):

A simple hook that will work with the default breakpoints of xs,sm,md,lg and xl. This hook works with material ui version 5.11.x. You could extend this with more functions relating to the breakpoint. For example when using with props instead of using props.size you could use props[getBreakPointName()].size for a responsive size value.

useBreakpoint.js Hook

```
import { useMediaQuery, useTheme } from "@mui/material";

/**
 * useBreakpoint
 * 
 * @returns 
 */
const useBreakpoint = () => {

/**
 * useTheme
 */
const theme = useTheme();

/**
 * useMediaQuery
 * 
 */
const mq_xs = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.only('xs'));
const mq_sm = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.only('sm'));
const mq_md = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.only('md'));
const mq_lg = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.only('lg'));
const mq_xl = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.only('xl'));

/**
 * getBreakPointName
 * 
 */
const getBreakPointName = () => {

    if(mq_xs){
        return "xs"
    }
    if(mq_sm){
        return "sm"
    }
    if(mq_md){
        return "md"
    }
    if(mq_lg){
        return "lg"
    }
    if(mq_xl){
        return "xl"
    }

}

return {
    getBreakPointName
}
}

export default useBreakpoint
```

Comment: This is the best version!

Answer (score 1):

It work with this code, if dont want to use typescript just remove the types.

```
const theme = useTheme();

const keys: readonly Breakpoint[] = [...theme.breakpoints.keys].reverse();

return (
   keys.filter((key: Breakpoint) => {
       // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
       const matches = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.up(key));

       if (matches) return true;
       return false;
   }, null)[0] ?? "xs"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a custom hook that'd suit your needs.

```
import {
  Breakpoint,
  Theme,
  useMediaQuery,
  useTheme
} from '@mui/material/styles'

/**
 * taken from https://material-ui.com/components/use-media-query/#migrating-from-withwidth
 *
 * Be careful using this hook. It only works because the number of
 * breakpoints in theme is static. It will break once you change the number of
 * breakpoints. See https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level
 */
type BreakpointOrNull = Breakpoint | null

export const useWidth = (): Breakpoint => {
  const theme: Theme = useTheme()
  const keys: readonly Breakpoint[] = [...theme.breakpoints.keys].reverse()
  return (
    keys.reduce((output: BreakpointOrNull, key: Breakpoint) => {
      // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
      const matches = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.up(key))
      return output != null && matches ? key : output
    }, null) ?? 'xs'
  )
}
```

Usage

```
const breakpoint = useWidth()
```